# Не работает горячая перезагрузка XAML для Uno Platform в VS Code

Tags: c#, xaml, uno

Как включить горячую перезагрузку для XAML в VS Code для Uno Platfom?

ОС: Linux mint 21.2 x64

Версия dot net: SDK: 7.0.400, Host: 7.0.10

Установил шаблоны, установил расширение для VS. Настроил launch.json, settings.json, tasks.json.

Все запускается, работает. Однако ни в режиме отладки, ни без нее горячая перезагрузка так и не работае для XAML.

Comment: VS Code это блокнот на стероидах, а не полноценная IDE, не ждите от блокнота всех возможностей полноценной студии. Если хотите конкретики, то в Code нет Hot Reload для XAML, а если смотреть на [это](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5034), то вряд-ли будет. Hot Reload для XAML даже в Rider не добавили (есть только небольшой огрызок), а вы хотите этого в блокноте...

Comment: Но дело в том, что во многих видео горячая перезагрузка в VS Code таки работает.

Comment: Например? Я ни разу не видел чтоб **XAML** обновляли через Code, студия да, сам пользуюсь, но Code, она способна только сайты обновлять в реал тайме, и то с бубном.

Comment: Вот пример:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zb2O7mtVxQ

Comment: Ладно, убедили. Советую тогда начать с [документации](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/working-with-xaml-hot-reload.html), почитать как настроить, что включать, что ставить, а также как отловить проблемы.